# Send user id to Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there method to log user id and later sort exception/crashes by specific user? Of course I  can put user id into `ExceptionParser.getDescription` but then it will just string messy data in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send custom dimensions with any analytics data. You need to set up a custom dimension on the analytics web interface first. Have a read through [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/customdimsmets).

Then when you handle your exception, you can send your custom dimension (user id).

For example:

```
        EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);
        //get google analytics to parse the exception
        String parsedException = new StandardExceptionParser(this, null).getDescription(Thread.currentThread().getName(), e);
        //get google analytics to build the map data to send, as well as our userId
        Map<String, String> exceptionMap = MapBuilder.createException(parsedException, false).set("userId", userId).build();
        //send our data!
        easyTracker.send(exceptionMap);
```

In the analytics web interface, in the Crashes and Exceptions view, you can add a secondary dimension to sort by, which in this case would the custom dimension (user id) that you defined.

Edit: As a side note, if you haven't heard of Crashlytics, it's pretty good for crash reporting too (and free!). It has similar support for sending custom data with a crash.